# Why does div that appears on hover start flickering when cursor is on top?

Tags: jquery, css

So I have 3 divs.  One is the parent container and on hover, 2 other containers should appear on top of the parent container.  One container is just some text and a black background, the other is just a gradient black background.

The issue I'm having is that when I hover over one of the child containers with text, it starts flickering and im not sure why.

Also, for some reason the child divs in my codepen appear over the entire window rather than just the parents div.  But the main issue is the flickering.

```
<div class="masonry-grid">
  <div class="asset-container" style="border: 1px solid rgb(71, 71, 75); margin: 5px; padding: 5px; margin:auto; width:200px;display:block"">
      <div class=" show-hover"></div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1593005510329-8a4035a7238f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" class="img-responsive center-img" style="position: relative; width:200px;">
      <div class="asset-title">
        filename
        size: 1mb
        <br>
        tag count: 1 Tag
        <br>
        uploaded: yesterday
      </div>
  <div class="masonry-footer"><span class="h5 card-title">description</span></div>
</div>
```

```
.asset-title{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-100px;
}

.show-hover:hover ~ .asset-title {
  display:block;
  left:0;
  padding-left:13px;
  margin-left:10px;
  padding-right:8px;
  padding-top:6px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  z-index:30;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.show-hover{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 29;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 32%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5284488795518207) 100%);
  opacity:0;
}

.show-hover:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

https://codepen.io/benjermann/pen/YzpJJXN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because '.show-hover' and '.asset-title' are sibling elements.

You put '.show-hover:hover ~.asset-title' and '.show-hover:hover' is canceled when mouse hover over '.asset-title'.

When that happens, the display of '.asset-title' becomes none, and '.show-hover:hover' is activated.

It looks like it's flickering because it repeats this process indefinitely.

To fix this, I recommend applying hover to the parent element.

Finally, if you want to put the 'position: absolute' element inside the parent element, you can use 'position: relative'.

```css
.asset-container {
    position: relative;
}

.asset-title {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 30;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.asset-container:hover .asset-title {
    display: block;
}

.show-hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 29;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 32%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5284488795518207) 100%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.asset-container:hover .show-hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry-grid">
    <div class="asset-container" style="border: 1px solid rgb(71, 71, 75); margin: 5px; padding: 5px; margin:auto; width:200px;display:block">
        <div class=" show-hover"></div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1593005510329-8a4035a7238f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" class="img-responsive center-img" style="position: relative; width:200px;">
        <div class="asset-title">
            filename
            size: 1mb
            <br>
            tag count: 1 Tag
            <br>
            uploaded: yesterday
        </div>

        <div class="masonry-footer"><span class="h5 card-title">card title</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```